# threading infinity loop java

Tags: java, multithreading

Inside a method, I start a thread that waits for user input (swing pushbutton).
Only after that input, the thread can be closed and the method returns a value.
My problem is that the code waiting for the input is not run inside that thread, but elsewhere:

```
String returnString = "";
Thread waitThread = new Thread(
                () -> {
                    while (xy == null) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            throw THREAD_INTERRUPTED.toException();
                        }
                    }
                }, "waitThread"
            );

waitThread.start();

try {
    waitThread.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    throw THREAD_INTERRUPTED.toException();
}

// -> wait for user input -> xy != null -> waitThread ends -> main thread joins -> continue code:

returnString = xy;

return ReturnString;
```

Why is this necessary? Because the method **has to** return the value (xy) that is set elsewhere by clicking a pushbutton.

The code above just ends up in an infinity loop, not allowing any interaction with the swing components.

Not being a pro in swing, I suppose the main thread is meant to catch interaction events. Since it is stuck in the `waitThread.join();` , thats not possible. Correct?

Is there a way to restructure this?

Comment: 'Since it is stuck in the `waitThread.join();` thats not possible. Correct?'. Correct

Comment: This sounds quite nonstandard as you described it. Can you provide some context  on how this thing you're trying to do looks from the app user perspective?

Comment: could you show the part where your "xy" has been declared? probably you need to declare it as "volatile" in order for the changes to be visible in other threads

Comment: It is non-standard, since there is a certain functionality I have to mimic. As I said, the method above is called, then starts to wait for the input and then has to return a value, while somewhere else (...) the actual frontend is actually listening for the input.

Comment: To answer jannis' question: The method opens a popup window that holds lets say two buttons. Each button sets a specific return value for the popup, which is then returned by the same method. So the method needs to open and close the popup. I know this is stupid, but it has to be this way. The setup would work, if I could keep interaction with the frontend enabled while waiting somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel? Plenty of ways to do this out-of-the-box:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String message = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What are you gonna tell me?");
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

[image: JOptionPane]

Comment: I work on an existing framework with tight restrictions. There is an abstraction layer that seperates the backend from the frontend. That means I cant insert Java Swing operations wherever I want to. I basically have to build this waiting machine programmatically.

Comment: "That means I cant insert Java Swing operations wherever I want to." - you are being very cryptic. Please elaborate more on your restrictions. Which "Swing operations" are you allowed to do and which not? Because, obviously you are using some (like the button control you mentioned).

Comment: I am being cryptic because I feel like the question is independent of which Swing components are being used. The modal windows dont disable interaction, the infinity loop does. Also, I am not part of the frontend team, so I dont code on the Swing level.

Comment: "The modal windows dont disable interaction" - wrong. Quoting [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) "In user interface design for computer applications, a modal window is a graphical control element subordinate to an application's main window. It creates a mode that disables the main window, but keeps it visible with the modal window as a child window in front of it. Users must interact with the modal window before they can return to the parent application."

Comment: Sorry, I misphrased that. I know that a modal window is supposed to disallow interaction. It shouldnt however cause a "loading circle" to appear, which is the case with my code. This rather indicates an infinity loop in my opinion. Thats what I meant to say. In any case, a modal window should at least still be sensitive itself, right? Really, my question is not that connected to Swing, I feel, since I basically have to solve it, without relying on Swing functionality. BTW I discovered that the thread listening for events is still running throughout the code execution, so thats even stranger.

Comment: @Phisc I know you said "without relying on Swing functionality" but when you use a `JButton` or `JFrame` or `JDialog`, those are, by definition, Swing. Why are you limited to not using Swing? You are basically trying to homebrew your own version of Swing because you aren't allowed to use it. But then again you are still using elements of Swing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going down the wrong route.

Clicking a button leads to an event, and then there should be an `ActionListener` reacting to that.

And that listener could update some "statish" thingy, and your other thread is reading that information.

Comment: The event handling is in place. My question is, how do I wait for an input at a very specific point of my code execution...

Answer (score 0):

> To answer jannis' question: The method opens a popup window that holds lets say two buttons. Each button sets a specific return value for the popup, which is then returned by the same method. So the method needs to open and close the popup. I know this is stupid, but it has to be this way. The setup would work, if I could keep interaction with the frontend enabled while waiting somehow.

Judging from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51138166/threading-infinity-loop-java/51163150#comment89287156_51138166) you seem to be trying to rediscover what is called a "modal dialog" and it's not stupid, at all. Please see the official documentation about dialogs in Swing: [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)
.